# MySQL Left JOIN Group_concat Performance issues

Tags: php, mysql, sql, left-join, group-concat

Please I need a help. I have a query I run to fetch data from two tables, but its consuming a lot of memory it takes as much as 9 seconds to fetch about 100 records. I may need to fetch up to 200k records at some point. Please how do I optimize this query?

```
  SELECT user_id AS id, name, address, phone, city, book_title 
  FROM users us LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  (SELECT bid, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT book_title SEPARATOR ' ') 
   AS book_title FROM user_books GROUP BY bid)bo ON bo.bid = us.user_id
```

On the user_books table I have multiple entries of book_titles for some users, I want to return a result that includes all the users both with a book title or not and the book_title in one column.

I ran an sql explain statement for the query and got this

```
id | select_type  | table   | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra
1     PRIMARY      us         ALL      NULL          NULL   NULL     NULL  168272
1     PRIMARY     <derived2>  ALL      NULL          NULL   NULL     NULL  65900
2     DERIVED     user_books  ALL      NULL           uid   4        NULL  164989
```

Note: I have an index for columns bid, book_title, user_id, name, address, phone, city in their respective tables.

Please any suggestions on how to boost the performance.

Comment: bo.bid = u.user_id !?!? are you sure?

Comment: sorry typo error bo.bid=us.user_id

Comment: Something called bid equals something called user_id. I'm glad I'm not the DBA !?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you need to create derived table? why not this way:

```
SELECT 
user_id, name, address, phone, city, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT book_title SEPARATOR ' ')  book_title 
FROM 
users us 
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_books ub ON ub.bid = us.user_id
GROUP BY us.user_id
```

Comment: with your query it fetches only users with book_title record only

Comment: Ok, group it by us.user_id, makes sense?

Comment: Bearing in mind the original question raised was regarding performance - is there not a more performant way to do this?  I've tried using this answer in my scenario and though it does works it is quite slow to execute.  I fear it is not a very scalable solution.  thanks

Answer (score 1):

try this - **much** more performant than the other answer given here.  Doing it this way prevents a lot of overhead in determining the grouping for each user_id, and you can always just add a WHERE clause to the selection from the users table if required.

```
SELECT
*,
  ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT book_title SEPARATOR ' ')
    FROM user_books ub
    WHERE ub.bid=us.id
  ) AS book_title
FROM
 ( SELECT user_id AS id, name, address, phone, city, book_title 
   FROM users
 ) us
```

Comment: Some users don't have records for books and those users needs to be returned in the query, will this query work in such scenario?

Comment: hey andy - yes indeed it does - I wondered the same when I first came across the solution which was an adaptation of a posting on another forum.  I can confirm if there are no books for a given user then the derived field 'book_title' in the query will simply contain NULL. regards

Comment: I did some test on my localhost, the first answer returns results in faster than the above query. I don't know if you have a different scenario. Can you kindly show results on the performance from your end? First answer Results - Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 72 total, Query took 0.0013 sec) ||||
Above Answer Results - Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 72 total, Query took 0.1015 sec)

Comment: hey andy I've had a look but its been a few weeks and I'm struggling to unpick my SQL to test it for you. But my tests were against a more complex set of combined tables - one contains 15,000 rows another contains 45,000. You need to rerun your own tests with a lot more data to eek out any performance issues. I'm really stacked up at the moment but if I can find time in the next couple of days I'll have another look and see if I can evidence it for you.  regards

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved my life! I was struggling with an entity that has a lot of m-to-n relationships which I wanted to fetch with INNER JOIN. Now I'm just doing a lot of subqueries. Your method has the best performance, fetching over 2000 rows with 15 m-to-n's each in under 500ms.